# Woocommerce - [product_categories] shortcode - How do I exclude two categories from the list?

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, categories

All the categories are displayed using the [product_categories] shortcode, displaying thumbnails as is usual. How do I target specific (two of them currently) categories not to show up or be hidden.

I have tried by putting those two categories at the bottom of the category `list` (so that it doesn't affect the product loop display visually) and then using `CSS` code:

```
.home .woocommerce ul.products li:last-of-type {
  display: none;
}
```

But this only targets the last one and not the second last one. Is there perhaps a way to say something like last-of-type minus one?

I somehow feel that `CSS` may not be the best way to achieve this, and instead use wordpress hooks.

Any input is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `nth-last-child()`

> The :nth-last-child(n) selector matches every element that is the nth child, regardless of type, of its parent, counting from the last child.

Try something like this:

```
.home .woocommerce ul.products li:nth-last-child(-n+2) {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: Brilliant! That worked. I need to read up more and get my head around the nth child concept. Thank you very much. Trying to understand the -n+2 story

Comment: `-n+2` is used for last two children

Comment: Ok, it's getting clearer for me, but why '-n'? Logically I would have thought just 'n' would be the last one.

Comment: There's a snag with using this CSS. If there are no products in the (last) category I'm trying to hide from the category list, it hides the previous category which is legitamite. Any way around this? Also I came across the following article but it shows how to do a filter on products, not category. I assume a similar method for category? http://www.sourcexpress.com/exclude-category-woocommerce-product-shortcode/#comment-9228